# Matplotlib arrow in loglog plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw an arrow into a loglog plot with matplotlib, which looks like this:

[image]

I know that it has been suggested to turn off the axis ([Matplotlib: Draw a vertical arrow in a log-log plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782094/matplotlib-draw-a-vertical-arrow-in-a-log-log-plot)), but I do need the axes. In addition, the suggestion did not seem to change anything (apart from turning the axes off, as expected):

```
plt.figure();plt.loglog([1,10,60],[1,0.1,0.005])
plt.axis('off')
plt.arrow(2,0.002,5,0.098,'k',head_length=0.3)
```

My work around so far has been to create an invisible inset (meaning: axes off) with a linear axes environment and plot the arrow in the inset, which works but is really a bit unpleasant. Is there a simpler way? Or do people recommend to add these type of additional features with eg. inkscape, after the main plot is done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`plt.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate) rather than `plt.arrow`. This is noted in the [documentation for `plt.arrow`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.arrow):

> The resulting arrow is affected by the axes aspect ratio and limits.
>   This may produce an arrow whose head is not square with its stem. To
>   create an arrow whose head is square with its stem, use `annotate()`

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.loglog([1,10,60],[1,0.1,0.005])
plt.annotate('', xy=(5, 0.098), xytext=(2, 0.002), 
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.),
            )

plt.ylim(0.001, 10)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that you may need to adjust the axes limits to fit the arrow into the plot. Here I had to change `ylim`.